# matching strings in list against strings python

Tags: python-2.7, search, string-matching

Say I have a list `match = ['one', 'two', 'three']`

and I have a list of arguments `foo = ['something', 'something_two', 'something', (...)]`

I want to only do an operation on the item if it matches any of the items in the `match` list:

```
for each in foo:
    for match_item in match:
        if match_item not in each:
            no_match = True
            break
    if no_match:
        break
    # do the desired operations
```

But I don't know how to make it so that it doesn't fail the match when `'something_two'` comes up against `'one'` and breaks all of the loops. The items in `match` will be only a part of the whole string in the items of `foo`, that's why I was looping through the list of items in `match`.

What would be a good way of approaching this?

Comment: Can't you just do `if each in match: # do desired op` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the list by using a generator expression with a condition:

```
for each in (item for item in foo if item in match):
    # do the desired operations
```

or by using `filter` function:

```
for each in filter(lambda item: item in match, foo):
    # do the desired operations
```

Comment: Will the first method work if `item` contains more characters than the ones in `match[0]` ? say that `each = 'something_one'` and match is only `'one'`

I can't seem to make it work

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is

```
for item in foo:
    if item in match:
        # do desired operations
```

or if you want to do the operations on the list itself

```
for i in range(len(foo)):
    if foo[i] in match:
        # do desired operation on foo[i]
```